# Integer option does not work (discord.js v14)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

so I am trying to use the .addOptionInteger option, but it isn't working

```
.setName('add')
    .setDescription('Add coins to your current balance')
        .addIntegerOption(option =>
            option.setName("amount")
                .setDescription("amount of coins")
                .setMinValue(0)
                .setMaxValue(22)
                ),
```

And this to fetch it

`const AddCoins = options.getInteger('amount');`

But it keeps giving me this error:

`Error: TypeError [CommandInteractionOptionType]: Option "amount" is of type: 3; expected 4.`

I tried to look through the discordjs documentation, but there is only stuff about the options likes String etc.

Answer (score 1):

The origin of this error is not within the slash command builder but rather the way you are fetching the command parameters in your code.

i.e. Somewhere you are probably using `<CommandInteractionOptionResolver>#getString` instead of `<CommandInteractionOptionResolver>#getInteger`

Dont forget theres the `<CommandInteractionOptionResolver>#get` method which resolves a `CommandInteractionOption` typedef which has a `value` property holding the value of said parameter (when using typescript make sure to cast the proper type.)

[<CommandInteractionOptionsResolver>#get](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteractionOptionResolver?scrollTo=get)
[<CommandInteractionOption>](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CommandInteractionOption)

The exact origin of your error in the discord.js library can be viewed [here](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/e3cbd45e7de069432818148b9dedda03f630f9f7/src/structures/CommandInteractionOptionResolver.js#L97)

Comment: Thanks. I was using `getNumber` instead of `getInteger` due to a copy/paste error.